# Create indicator variables of holidays from a date column

Tags: r, variables, dataframe

I am still a bonehead novice so forgive me if this is a simple question, but I can't find the answer on stackoverflow.  I  would like to create a set of indicator variables for each of the major US holidays, just by applying a function to my date field that can detect which days are holidays and then I could us Model.matrix etc.. to convert to a set of indicator variables.
For example, I have daily data from Jan 1 2012 through September 15th, 2013 and I would like to create a variable indicator for Easter.

I am currently using the `timeDate` package to pass a year to their function `Easter()` to find the date. I then type the dates into the following code to create an indicator variable.

```
Easter(2012)
EasterInd2012<-as.numeric(DATASET$Date=="2012-04-08")
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The easiest way to get a general holiday indicator variable is to create a vector of all the holidays you're interested in and then match those dates in your data frame. Something like this should work:

```
library(timeDate)

# Sample data
Date <- seq(as.Date("2012-01-01"), as.Date("2013-09-15"), by="1 day")
DATASET <- data.frame(rnorm(624), Date)

# Vector of holidays
holidays <- c(as.Date("2012-01-01"), 
              as.Date(Easter(2013)),
              as.Date("2012-12-25"),
              as.Date("2012-12-31"))

# 1 if holiday, 0 if not. Could also be a factor, like c("Yes", "No")
DATASET$holiday <- ifelse(DATASET$Date %in% holidays, 1, 0)
```

You can either manually input the dates, or use some of `timeDate`'s built-in holiday functions (the `listHolidays()` function shows all those). So you could also construct `holidays` like so:

```
holidays <- c(as.Date("2012-01-01"), 
              as.Date(Easter(2013)),
              as.Date(USLaborDay(2012)),
              as.Date(USThanksgivingDay(2012)),
              as.Date(USMemorialDay(2012)),
              as.Date("2012-12-25"),
              as.Date("2012-12-31"))
```

To get specific indicators for each holiday, you'll need to do them one at a time:

```
EasterInd2012 <- ifelse(DATASET$Date==as.Date(Easter(2012)), 1, 0)
LaborDay2012 <- ifelse(DATASET$Date==as.Date(UsLaborDay(2012)), 1, 0)
# etc.
```

Comment: You could potentially make the specific indicators assignment more efficient by write a loop with one of the `apply` functions, but then you'd need to define the variable names and dates, which is just as much work as doing it one line at a time like this. So it's not the most efficient, computatively speaking, but it works.